# How to blur the edges of a image

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to blur the edges of a image the approach i took was to render the image to a frame buffer and than apply gaussian blur to it.

than i tried to overlay the actual image on top of the blurred image but this approach does not seem to work.

[image]

As this does not give a blur effect around the edges but the blurred image moves away.

Please suggest me the ways i can achieve this or if you can show me how this can be done in the fragment shader.

The code

```
// Generate frame buffers
         glGenFramebuffers(2, pingpongFBO);
    glGenTextures(2, pingpongBuffer);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pingpongFBO[i]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pingpongBuffer[i]);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA,
            GL_FLOAT, NULL);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D,pingpongBuffer[i],0);
    }


// blur the image
        bool horizontal = true, first_iteration = true;
        float blurValue = 6;
        GLint drawFrameBuffer;
        int amount = blurValue;
        shaderBlur.use();
        shaderBlur.setInt("image", 0);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pingpongFBO[horizontal]);
        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pingpongFBO[!horizontal]);
        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            shaderBlur.setInt("horizontal", horizontal);
            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pingpongFBO[horizontal]);
            if (first_iteration)
            {
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image.textureID);
                glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            }
            else
            {
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pingpongBuffer[!horizontal]);
                glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            }
            renderQuadInner();
            horizontal = !horizontal;
            if (first_iteration)
                first_iteration = false;
        }   


   // Map the image
        shader.use();
        shader.setInt("u_tex", 0);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); // the default frame buffer
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);               
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pingpongBuffer[horizontal]);  // the blurred image
        renderQuad(); 
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image.textureID);  // the actual image
        renderQuad();
```

The blur shader

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 TexCoords;
uniform sampler2D image;
uniform bool horizontal;
float offset[3] = float[]( 0.0, 1.3846153846, 3.2307692308 );
uniform float weight[3] = float[] (0.2270270270, 0.316216162, 0.0702702703);

void main()
{             
    vec2 tex_offset = 3.0 / textureSize(image, 0); // gets size of single texel
    vec4 result = texture(image, TexCoords).rgba * weight[0];
    vec2 uv = TexCoords.xy;
     if(horizontal)
     {
         for(int i = 1; i < 3; ++i)
         {
            result += texture(image, TexCoords + vec2(tex_offset.x * i, 0.0)).rgba * weight[i];
            result += texture(image, TexCoords - vec2(tex_offset.x * i, 0.0)).rgba * weight[i];
         
         }
     }
     else
     {
         for(int i = 1; i < 3; ++i)
         {
             result += texture(image, TexCoords + vec2(0.0, tex_offset.y * i)).rgba * weight[i];
             result += texture(image, TexCoords - vec2(0.0, tex_offset.y * i)).rgba * weight[i];  
         }
     }
     FragColor = vec4(result);
}
```

Comment: The approach you have taken is very much correct, however, your implementation might have some issues. Please share a minimal reproducible code so we can see where the issue is.

Comment: @codetiger i have updated the code.

Comment: Looks like your `tex_offset` is bit huge. I am not sure why you are using 3.0 instead of the standard 1.0 in your `tex_offset` calculations

Comment: @codetiger The image is still offsetting even if i use 1.0

Comment: Please check this example, it works well if the offset is correct https://shaderfrog.com/app/view/1669

Comment: @Summit, can you do a test for me? Modify your blur shader such that it just outputs the texture image, without doing any fancy effects and do a render. Show the result or at least let us know if the image still moves.

i.e just do `FragColor = texture(image, TexCoords);`

Comment: @Makogan i have tested and yes the image still moves.

Comment: Then it seems there's a difference in the vertex data you are sending to the gpu between  the 2 renders.